# Rest API: How to get all feeds, notes calls for a Case?

Tags: rest-api, case, case-object

Using the Rest API I am able to get a case:

https://XXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Case/500XXXXXXXXX

I need to also get all related Calls, Notes, Emails for this Case.

Can I get that in one REST request if I know the Case?

Comment: Have you checked the [Composite API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a SOQL query in the API to request for all the info related to case like below

```
/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=Select+Id,+(Select+Id+from+CombinedAttachments),+(Select+Id+from+Tasks),+(Select+Id+from+Emails)+from+case+where+Id='5004S000004Sdx5QAC'
```

Or there are other alternatives like using Composite [GraphAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) or using [GraphQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/graphql-about.html).